# Invalid spec cache file

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have ruby 2.0.0p247 [x64-mingw32] with Gem 2.2.2 installed on Windows 8. I have a persistent problem gem that is making it virtually unusable. Whenever I try to install a new gem, I invariably get:

```
ERROR: While executing gem ... Invalid spec cache file in C:/Users/...
```

In the past, I've been able to run `gem update` or `gem update --system` and that would clear up the problem for **one, single** `gem install`. Subsequent install would fail with the same error. Now even gem update fails with that error message.

I've tried deleting the `users/.../.gem` directory. When I do that, `gem update` recreates that directory and promptly fails with the same error message.

I re-installed ruby 1.9.8 with gems several times to try to cure the problem, then upgraded to ruby 2.0.0. Throughout all re-installs and upgrades, the problem persisted.

I'm at my wits end here. Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Here's the backtrace on the edit"

```
L:\xampp\htdocs\frameworks\yii2\framework>gem update --backtrace
Updating installed gems
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Invalid spec cache file in C:/Users/Larry/.gem/specs/rubygems.org%443/specs.4.8
        C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/source.rb:187:in `rescue in load_specs'
        C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/source.rb:179:in `load_specs'
        C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:266:in `tuples_for'
        C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:228:in `block in available_specs'
        C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:97:in `each'
        C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:97:in `each_source'
        C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:222:in `available_specs'
        C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:102:in `search_for_dependency'
        C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:113:in `fetch_remote_gems'
        C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:135:in `highest_remote_version'
        C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:264:in `block in which_to_update'
        C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:260:in `each'
        C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:260:in `which_to_update'
        C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:96:in `execute'
        C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/command.rb:305:in `invoke_with_build_args'
        C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:167:in `process_args'
        C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:137:in `run'
        C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:54:in `run'
        C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

Comment: paste the full error message with path and backtrace.

Comment: I don't have anything useful to say other than to commiserate. I'm sorry you're having such trouble. Did you install from source or use RailsInstaller?

Comment: what is yii2? what is the content of C:/Users/Larry/.gem/specs/rubygems.org%443/specs.4.8?

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402457/corrupted-ruby-gem-system

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but was able to fix it this way:

Delete the folder in `users/%user%/.gem/` and rerun the command `gem sources --update`

Hope this helps.