# Corrupted ruby gem system

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Somehow, my ruby gems got corrupted, and when I do

```
$ sudo gem update
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Invalid spec cache file in /home/sawa/.gem/specs/api.rubygems.org%443/specs.4.8
```

I removed `.gem`, and reinstalled Ruby, but the problem persists. How can I repair this?

Comment: Maybe try removing `~/.gem` again and `gem update --system` (as it may be a bug that was fixed in a newer RubyGems). Also, what Ruby version, RubyGems version, and any Ruby version manager (chruby, rbenv, RVM, etc.)?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Ruby is 2.2.0, Ruby gems is the one that came with it. I directly compiled from source and installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First I suggest you save your gem list, just in case:

```
$ gem list > gems.txt
```

To verify that you're using the SPEC CACHE that you think you are:

```
$ gem env | grep "SPEC CACHE"
 - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/sawa/.gem/specs
```

To see if you have any outdated sources:

```
$ gem sources
```

If you want to be careful, you can remove sources one by one, then re-add. (See code below)

Try pristine, though it will likely fail:

```
$ gem pristine --all
```

The harsh approach is to delete all the gem specs:

```
rm -rf /home/sawa/.gem/specs
```

The nuclear approach is to delete the gem directory, which you write that you've already tried:

```
rm -rf /home/sawa/.gem
```

My best guess is that one of your gem sources is returning an incorrect file, possibly a temporary problem. You can figure this out by removing all your gem sources.

```
$ gem sources -​-clear-all # clears the cache, but doesn't remove the source
$ gem sources --update  # probably will work, in which case you can stop now.
```

If clearing the sources doesn't work, then you can remove all and re-add:

```
$ gem sources 
$ gem sources --remove http://gems.rubyforge.org/
$ gem sources --remove http://gems.github.com
...etc ...
$ gem sources -​-update  # should work fine, because there are no sources
$ gem sources --add http://gems.rubyforge.org/
$ gem sources --update
$ gem sources --add http://gems.github.com
$ gem sources --update
...etc...
```

Comment: I think `gem sources --clear-all` and `gem sources --update` did it. That was the answer. Thanks.