# Invalid spec cache file in .../latest-specs.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemset

I have a similar problem to: [Invalid spec cache file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22690978/invalid-spec-cache-file) 
but it does not have an answer.

Our rails app recently upgraded from ruby 2.1.2 to 2.1.5

When I downloaded this onto my laptop (desktop working fine) it required be to rvm install 2.1.5, then create a new gemset for 2.1.5

I tried to run bundle and bundler isn't installed so I tried `gem install bundler` and it responded with the following error message:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Invalid spec cache file in /my_dir/.gem/specs/api.rubygems.org%443/latest_specs.4.8
```

On checking that directory, I find that there is a `specs.4.8` file but not a `latest_specs.4.8` file

Things I tried:

- I deleted and re-created the gemset, same problem.
- I ran `gem update`
- I blew away `/my_dir/.gem/specs` and reran `gem update`
- I ran `gem update --system`
- I reinstalled ruby 2.1.5 and did it all again...

When I changed the ruby-version back to 2.1.2 and used `rvm use 2.1.2; bundle` it didn't have a problem (but then bundler already exists in that gemset).

Gem env:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.5 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 273) [x86_64-darwin10.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /my_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /my_dir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /my_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /my_dor/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /my_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5
     - /my_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
gem sources --clear-all
gem sources --update
```

If that doesn't work, see my longer answer here: [Corrupted ruby gem system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402457/corrupted-ruby-gem-system/28403009#28403009)

Comment: thanks - haven't had a chance to try that yet (I'm back on the desktop today) but that sounds like a good list of things to look at.

Comment: Do you happen to know why latest_specs vs specs ? have rubygems changed something about what to name the file the specs are in?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I gave up and reinstalled ruby 2.1.5 and deleted the gemset.

Then it turned out I could install without bothering to first create a gemset.

Just `rvm use 2.1.5` then `gem install bundler` then `bundle`

So: no idea what went wrong (and would still encourage others to answer for an explanation), but this is what worked for me.